# Is there standard terminology for any or all of these concepts designed to help with thinking about Riemann integrability?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders, riemann-integration

When trying to determine whether a function $f$ is Riemann integrable or not, we're typically in the following situation:

- Write $U_f(P)$ and $L_f(P)$ for the corresponding "upper Riemann sum" and "lower Riemann sum" with respect to a partition $P$.
- Hence $\mathrm{img}(U_f)$ and $\mathrm{img}(L_f)$ denote the set of upper sums and the set of lower sums respectively.
- Whenever $B$ and $A$ are subsets of the real line, write $B \geq A$ to mean the following: $$\mathop{\forall}_{b \in B, a \in A}b \geq a$$
- We know that $\mathrm{img}(U_f) \geq \mathrm{img}(L_f).$
- We want to know whether or not $\mathrm{inf}(\mathrm{img}(U_f)) = \mathrm{sup}(\mathrm{img}(L_f))$, i.e. whether or not these sets are "touching"; if they are, then the Riemann integral of $f$ exists, and if not, then not.

To reduce my overall feelings of confusion about this situation, I decided to try "doing maths" on it, which for me usually involves coming up with definitions, notation and terminology to help "conceptualize around" the situation. Here's what I came up with.

Whenever $P$ is a poset, write $\overline{P}$ for the collection of pairs $(B,A)$ of non-empty subsets of $C$ satisfying $B \geq A$.

Also, call $(B,A) \in \overline{P}$ *touching* iff there is at most one $p \in P$ with $B \geq p \geq A$. (By this inequality, I mean what you think I mean.)

Now assuming $P$ is conditionally complete, we have functions $$\overline{\inf}, \overline{\sup}:\overline{P} \rightarrow P$$ given as follows:

$$\overline{\inf}(B,A) = \mathrm{inf}(A), \qquad \overline{\sup}(B,A) = \mathrm{sup}(A)$$

Its clear that $\overline{\inf} \geq \overline{\sup}$ holds pointwise; furthermore, it can be seen that being a touching element of $\overline{P}$ is equivalent to being an element of the equalizer of $\overline{\inf}$ and $\overline{\sup}$.

There's also an obvious way to order $\overline{P}$; we find that $\overline{\inf}$ becomes antitone and $\overline{\sup}$ becomes monotone. With appropriate tweaks to this, we can probably show that the touching pairs are precisely the maximal elements of $\overline{P}$. I haven't thought about the details.

We can also show that if $P$ equals $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, then $(B,A) \in \overline{P}$ is touching iff for all $\varepsilon \in P,$ there exists $b \in B$ and $a \in A$ such that $\varepsilon \geq b-a.$ A reasonable question to ask is: how far can this be generalized?

Anyway, what I'd like to know is:

> **Question.** Is there standard terminology or notation for any or all of the above concepts or variants thereon?

Comment: Given the limitations of Riemann integration, going all-out to generalize something that really doesn't come up much except in proving that certain moderately large class of functions (continuous, except for finitely many discontinuities, typically) is integrable, generalizing it and fancying up the terminology doesn't seem worth it. To partly answer what you asked: *I* don't know any terminology for these things.

Comment: @JohnHughes, this is hardly "all-out." Its just meant to clarify what the hell is really going on.

Comment: Look up Poset (partially ordered set), Lattice, Complete Lattice, Net, and Filter.

Comment: @user254665, given that I use the terms poset and "conditionally complete" in my question, I'd say your comment misses the mark a bit. Its worth noting that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't a complete lattice; we can make it complete, of course, by adding two points, but the larger set cannot be made into a commutative ring in a way that extends the usual ring structure of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "Mathematicians are like frenchmen. Whatever you say to them they put into their own language, and thereafter it is something completely different." --Goethe.  I learned this material almost 50 years ago and have taught it multiple times, and yet your "clarification" manages to make me find the ideas *more* confusing rather than less. Spivak's *"Calculus"* does a fine job of explaining this stuff in quite elementary terms (or at least it did for me). One man's meat is another's poison, I suppose. If you want to generalize, go for it. But my experience suggests your audience may be limited.